# eclipse svn plugin change

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I need to change eclipse svn plugin, but I want to know if it is not a way to download from other plugin after deleting project

The original SVN plugin name is subclipse and the plugin to replace is Subversive

In summary, if I am using Subclipse and want to change to Subversive, is there any other way than deleting the project?

Comment: Why do you want to delete the project? If you switch between Subclipse and Subversive, just make sure to uninstall the previous plug-in first since both have equal or similar named menus and dialogs, which would otherwise be confusing. Before uninstalling, you probably need to disconnect the SVN projects and after installing the new plug-in, re-share them (right-click the project and choose _Team > Share Project..._).

Comment: Why do you want to switch to Subversive from Subclipse?